# How to check whether a checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, forms

Here is something I have now:
I've got a checkbox, which I need to verify whether it is selected.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="person_info_check" value="0" &nbps>Read and agree!</input>
```

But when I tried to use the way I had searched through the Internet, I found I couldn't catch the checkbox and thus verify.

This is how I grab the checkbox:

```
        if($('#person_info_check').is(':checked')){
            if(confirm("Are you sure to submit?")){
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }
        else{
            alert("Please read the file and agree the statement!");
            return false;
        }
```

And I've also tried this:

```
        var checkbox = document.getElementsByName("person_info_check");

        if(checkbox[0].checked==false){
            alert("Please read the file and agree the statement!");
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: What is `&nbps` supposed to be?

Comment: Your `confirm(...")` is missing the opening quote

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$('#person_info_check')` that is actually a jQuery ID Selected while in your HTML you specified the `name="person_info_check"` so your element is not getting selected.

Try specifying the `id="person_info_check"` in your checkbox element. Most of the jQuery code should work.

Or you can use the JQuery name selector.

```
$("input[value='person_info_check]")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that person_info_check is not the id of your input but the name attribute. You should use this:
`$("input[name='person_info_check']").is(':checked');`

Answer (score 0):

There are major errors in your code such as:

1. Input type `checkbox` does not require any value tag
2. Input type does not require to have a closing tag
3. Input type does not entertain the HTML text; it only can have value or checked status according to the tag type.

More details of the input tag can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input). An example of code is as follows:

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementById("che");

if (checkbox.checked == true) {
  alert('I am checked')
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="person_info_check" id='che' checked/> <label for='che'>I am checkbox</label>
```